# Програмирование на планшете

Tags: php, android

Ребята, сталкнулся с проблемой. Ищу текстовый редактор для планшета с возможностью отображения мгновенного результата для веб-языков. Хабрахабр предложил платную версию.
Может, кто знает бесплатную, подскажите, премного буду благодарен. Необходимо писать php-скрипты с планшета, только вот не нахожу нужного приложения, которое сразу показывает результат в браузере или хоть как-то.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуй выполнить свой код онлайн http://www.compileonline.com/execute_php_online.php
Там есть много всяких языков программирования
http://www.compileonline.com/

Comment: Спасибо большое за онлайн, но если вдруг есть что то известное offline то это значительно упростит ситуацию/

Answer (score 1):

Не знаю насчет поддержки планшетов, но поробуйте online IDE:

[Koding](https://koding.com/)

[C9](https://c9.io/)

Answer (score 0):

> показывает результат в браузере

Вам нужен локальный веб-сервер для android. Есть отличная статья по этому поводу
https://habrahabr.ru/post/152965/
А вот и приложение:
http://4pda.ru/forum/index.php?showtopic=336768